# DataGridView detect changes not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview, datatable

I have a program that is going to load data into a DataGridView, where users can edit/add/delete data.  When they close out of the form, if there are any changes made, it will ask if the user wants to save the changes to the database.

So I have a DataTable that I load and assign to the DataSource of the DataGridView.  I can then make changes to the data within the table, and if I call the DataSet.Update method, it updates.

However, if I call the DataTable.GetChanges method and look to see the changes, I get nothing, unless I have tabbed/clicked/whatever off of the current row of the DataGridView (in which case .GetChanges works)  This leads me to believe that the changes are not committing to the DataTable unless the row loses focus.

So, is there a way to check to see if any cell is changed in a DataGridView, or a way to commit those changes without tabbing off of the row?

Again, this fails me if I don't change the row in the GridView, but works otherwise. I want it to work in both situations.

```
    Dim changedRows As New DataTable()
    changedRows = dtInfo.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified Or DataRowState.Added Or DataRowState.Deleted)
    If Not changedRows Is Nothing Then
    ....
    End If
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want "Or" rather than "And" ?

Comment: Yes, I do, I changed that hoping that it may have an effect, but didn't change back when I copied the code.  Same result with the Ors.  Updated question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [Form.ValidateChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159409.aspx) method, this will validate and commit all controls in the form, including your DataGridView. This method returns false if there is a validation error.

Comment: Thank you kindly.  Worked like a charm